# Android OS using around 500MB of RAM, is that normal?

Tags: ram, 6.0-marshmallow

I have a Nexus 5X, and was checking my memory use, as the phone is a tad slow at certain points, and it seems that the process "Android OS" consistently uses aroudn 500MB of RAM. Is that about a normal level, or is there anything I can do to improve this?

Also, Android System is my next highest offender, sitting at aroudn 150MB.

Comment: Weird. Even on my bloated SGS6 Edge Android-System only consumes 2.1 MB and I can't find Android OS. I guess it collects all the processes the system runs. 500MB are not that much in comparison to other devices.

Comment: Yeah it seemed strangely high to me. I've just done a restart of my phone, and I'm gonna leave it idle for a little while see if that goes down.